# RadioButtonList Convert the value to int as(id)

Tags: c#, string, dataset, int, radiobuttonlist

I have this problem : 
But i cloudn't convert the radiobuttonlist value to id

i have to insert the giving value or text in the id colum in my table.

```
 PhotoTableAdapter InsertPhotoInfo = new PhotoTableAdapter();
            InsertPhotoInfo.InsertPhoto(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, RadioButtonList1.Text);

  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatDirection="horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" CssClass="rdo" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1">Black</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2">Archi</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3">Qu</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4">Fun</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5"> Fash</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6">Peo</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="7" Value="7">Land</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8">City</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="9" Value="9">Transport</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**Code Behind File:**

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     { 
    String radioID = RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Value.ToString();
    int intID = Convert.ToInt32(radioID);
     { 
      PhotoTableAdapter InsertPhotoInfo = new PhotoTableAdapter();
  InsertPhotoInfo.InsertPhoto(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text,RadioButtonList1.radioID)); 
      } 
    }
```

i tried a lot of things but it keeps giving me errors so i gave up. 
However it says cannot convert from string to int.

Datatype : System.Int32  i need to get the number as the id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using `Text` Poperty of `RadioButtonList` , Use `Value` for getting the ID value as below:

```
String radioID=RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString()   
int intID=Convert.ToInt32(radioID);
```

while passing parameters you can pass `intID` as argument :

**Replace this :**

```
InsertPhotoInfo.InsertPhoto(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text,RadioButtonList1.radioID));
```

**With following:**

```
InsertPhotoInfo.InsertPhoto(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text,intID);
```

Comment: This what i tried so far but it says identifier expected.


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       

        String radioID = RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Value.ToString();
        int intID = Convert.ToInt32(radioID);
        {
            PhotoTableAdapter InsertPhotoInfo = new PhotoTableAdapter();
            InsertPhotoInfo.InsertPhoto(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text,RadioButtonList1.(radioID));
        }
        }

Comment: I am trying to insert the radio items values into column for id's.

Comment: i did not get you sorry, could you please give me some example?

Comment: How am i suppose to actually add it to my code ? as you can see my code.

Comment: Please Edit your Post/Question with the above code it's not readable.

Comment: this is the simplest way i can explain it... 
you see the radiobuttonlist ? 
as each item as a value, now i want that value to be inserted in column with datatype as int.

Comment: please see my edited answer.please let me know if you want to do something else.

Comment: However it works as i explained but the problem it only write  number 1 in the database table. so it should go by the selected one and takes it value and puts it in the database .

Comment: it works perfectly now check my edited answer, you should use SelectedValue instead of index of zero.

Comment: Yes, Works perfect :) .